# Single query in location tracking system

Tags: php, mysql, nested-loops

I have this system that keeps track of the location of items.

Example tables:

**constb**

```
consid cons
  1    Nint
  2    PS
  3    XB
  4    AT
```

**consloctb**

```
locid  consid  loc
  1       1     GS
  2       2     IT
  3       2     GG
  4       1     IG
  5       2     SS
  6       3     SM
  7       3     FB
  8       1     SS
  9       2     SM
  10      3     IT
  11      4     SM
```

And the result would show the current location of all the items. It would look like this:

```
Nint - SS
PS - SM
XB - IT
```

The logic I'm thinking right now is to do a nested loop.

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM constb ORDER BY id");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

  $consid=$row["consid"];

  $res2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM consloctb WHERE consid='$consid' ORDER BY locid DESC LIMIT 1");

  while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){

    echo $row["cons"]." - ".$row2["loc"];

  } /* END OF SECOND LOOP */

} /* END OF FIRST LOOP */
```

This would show the results that I wanted.

And if I add a search function, I would do the same nested loop process, just gonna add another WHERE condition in the second loop, if the searched location is the same with the `loc` column.

```
$srchloc=$_POST["search"]; /* DATA SUBMITTED */

$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM constb ORDER BY id");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

  $consid=$row["consid"];

  $res2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM consloctb WHERE consid='$consid' AND loc='$srchloc' ORDER BY locid DESC LIMIT 1");

  while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){

    echo $row["cons"]." - ".$row2["loc"];

  } /* END OF SECOND LOOP */

} /* END OF FIRST LOOP */
```

Example search, if a user search for items that is currently in the `SM`, the result would show

```
PS - SM
AT - SM
```

Doing the second option I think might slow the search process. How can I achieve this using a single query? Or making the process faster?

Comment: Wouldn't you place it in your sql query?

Comment: I don't see why something like this: `SELECT * FROM constloctb AS const_loc LEFT JOIN constb ON const_loc.consid = constb.id WHERE const_loc.loc='$srchloc' ORDER BY const_loc.locid` wouldn't work. That'll comp down on a lot of the processing you have to do. (*It's untested*)

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to list the current location of all the items:**

```
SELECT t.cons,
       t.loc
FROM
  (SELECT constb.consid AS id,
          constb.cons AS cons,
          consloctb.loc AS loc
   FROM constb
   LEFT JOIN consloctb ON constb.consid = consloctb.consid
   ORDER BY constb.consid,
            consloctb.locid DESC) AS t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

**If you want the result filtered for a searched location**, you can add the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT t.cons,
       t.loc
FROM
  (SELECT constb.consid AS id,
          constb.cons AS cons,
          consloctb.loc AS loc
   FROM constb
   LEFT JOIN consloctb ON constb.consid = consloctb.consid
   ORDER BY constb.consid,
            consloctb.locid DESC) AS t
GROUP BY t.id HAVING t.loc='SM';
```